# Comment boxes are wrong size

Tags: bug, ios-app

When showing all comments, there seems to be an OBOE error in computing the size of each comment's box. Some comments are cut off while others have white space at the end. Before/after shots attached. [image: some comments hidden]  [image: all comments visible, but sized wrong]

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPhone 5s (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 8.4.1 (Build 12H321)

Adding two more screenshots, after updating the app to 1.6.1 per the comments. Now, the comment will be wrong-sized, but if you scroll it up or down off-screen when you scroll it back, it will have the right dimension.

[image: before scroll]
[image: after scroll]

Comment: Can't repro here, I'm using the beta though so maybe it was fixed already. You should update to the latest version (latest is 1.6.1 I believe).

Comment: Still misbehaves with 1.6.1 but if you move the wrong-sized box out of the view, it will be correct-sized when it scrolls back. I'll add another pair of screenshots to illustrate. I'm pretty sure that scrolling had no effect in the older version, fwiw.